# How do I find which sound name belongs to which music file?

Tags: source-engine, half-life-2, hammer

In the *Hammer Editor*, I've decided on some background music I want to play, using *ambient_generic*, but I can't find the proper music file. I have gotten music running with the "#*[soundname]" in the sound to play, and it definitely plays music, but not the one I was looking for (I thought since the one is looking for is track 26 on the HL2 soundtrack, I would use that number in the sound name in-game - it plays music, but not the right one.)

I have looked through some of the files to find exactly what I want (that is where I found the "*#[soundname]" text), but I don't know which sound name belongs to which music. Is there a list somewhere, or how do I find it?

Comment: i used to use "twhl.info" it is very useful site for hl modders. there is a lot of exprerienced users. and youll see they are gonna make you a better mapper, if you let them teach you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to find the track list here:

http://combineoverwiki.net/wiki/Half-Life_2_soundtrack

A short tutorial on how to play music:

1. Create an ambient_generic entity. Give it a name, of course.
2. In the sound name property, put "*#music/" (without quotation marks) before the music name.
3. On the site above, find the track you want and paste the filename next to the "*#music/"
4. Set all your other settings - properties, flags (Set the play everywhere flag!), triggers, etc, boot it up and enjoy how much more delicious the music makes to your map.